# ¿Hay alguna manera de posicionar un ScrollView a un punto específico?

Tags: android, android-studio, scroll-view

Busco mover mi ScrollView a una posición en la que se pueda ver un LinearLayout que queda fuera de lo que se muestra en pantalla. El usuario puede pensar que no se realizó la tarea que esperaba y obviamente no quiero que piense eso.

He visto que en el auto-completado de Android Studio me presenta algo llamado 'scrollToDescendant':

```
miScrollView.scrollToDescendant(View child);
```

Pero requiere del API 29. La verdad no estoy seguro si este método hace lo que busco como parece que sí, a juzgar por como suena.

Quiero suponer que ha de existir otra forma sin utilizar un método que requiera una API tan nueva (la versión más baja que acepta mi app es la API 21).

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas posicionar un `ScrollView` en una vista especifica en este caso un `LinearLayout`, puedes realizarlo de esta forma mediante el método [smothScrollTo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView#smoothScrollTo(int,%20int)) en donde defines la coordenada X y Y de la vista:

```
miScrollView.smoothScrollTo(myLinearLayout.getScrollX(),myLinearLayout.getScrollY());
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó perfectamente. Nada más tuve que añadir la altura de mi LinearLayout para que se viera completo.